# Android packages are ignored when using VCPKG with manifest mode

Tags: android, c++, openssl, vcpkg

I was trying to install android libraries using vcpkg manifest, but they are simply skipped for some reason. I am lost, pls tell me what I am doing wrong.

This is my manifest:

```
{
    "name": "native-deps",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": [
        {
            "name": "openssl",        
            "version>=": "1.1.1n",
            "platform": "(x86 & android) | (x86 & windows)"
        }       
    ],                        
    "overrides": [
        { "name": "openssl", "version-string": "1.1.1n" },
        { "name": "abseil", "version-string": "20211102.1" }
    ],
    "builtin-baseline": "6e024e744e7717c06ddacd5089401109c6298553"
}
```

I am running this command:

```
vcpkg\vcpkg.exe --feature-flags="versions" install "--clean-after-build" "--x-install-root=.\vcpkg\installed" "--binarysource=clear;interactive;nuget,VCPkg"
```

This is the output:

```
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x86-windows...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    openssl[core]:x86-windows -> 1.1.1n -- D:\ripostecore\vcpkg\buildtrees\versioning_\versions\openssl\7e4d802e3bde4154c227c0dd1da75c719be9f07a
  * vcpkg-cmake[core]:x64-windows -> 2021-02-28#3 -- D:\ripostecore\vcpkg\buildtrees\versioning_\versions\vcpkg-cmake\0e8bb94599a00fd9c61fd0ae524c22a067c21420
  * vcpkg-cmake-config[core]:x64-windows -> 2021-05-22 -- D:\ripostecore\vcpkg\buildtrees\versioning_\versions\vcpkg-cmake-config\2d4f997a32b8e8bfe98d12beb2bfe6be713c7086
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
Attempting to fetch 3 packages from nuget.
NuGet Version: 5.11.0.10
Feeds used:
  https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json

Restoring NuGet package openssl_x86-windows.1.1.1-vcpkg6276bfbf618dc64e1eec5bff0593d9de2a6bef5a592c854b5f3d4940fe0ab899.
Restoring NuGet package vcpkg-cmake-config_x64-windows.2021.5.22-vcpkgf4c47ca8e826891cf4e637ebaecbd8499efa3f7762b8c83c7aee03e4d519a517.
Restoring NuGet package vcpkg-cmake_x64-windows.2021.2.28-vcpkgac851a136bb968268c3a69c870e0c3292e6c5d6a1f1ed3c70fec8c4868349def.
  GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/7b1cdcb8-1d57-4320-8e01-c0226dfce5fc/nuget/v3/flat2/vcpkg-cmake_x64-windows/2021.2.28-vcpkgac851a136bb968268c3a69c870e0c3292e6c5d6a1f1ed3c70fec8c4868349def/vcpkg-cmake_x64-windows.2021.2.28-vcpkgac851a136bb968268c3a69c870e0c3292e6c5d6a1f1ed3c70fec8c4868349def.nupkg
  GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/7b1cdcb8-1d57-4320-8e01-c0226dfce5fc/nuget/v3/flat2/openssl_x86-windows/1.1.1-vcpkg6276bfbf618dc64e1eec5bff0593d9de2a6bef5a592c854b5f3d4940fe0ab899/openssl_x86-windows.1.1.1-vcpkg6276bfbf618dc64e1eec5bff0593d9de2a6bef5a592c854b5f3d4940fe0ab899.nupkg
  GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/7b1cdcb8-1d57-4320-8e01-c0226dfce5fc/nuget/v3/flat2/vcpkg-cmake-config_x64-windows/2021.5.22-vcpkgf4c47ca8e826891cf4e637ebaecbd8499efa3f7762b8c83c7aee03e4d519a517/vcpkg-cmake-config_x64-windows.2021.5.22-vcpkgf4c47ca8e826891cf4e637ebaecbd8499efa3f7762b8c83c7aee03e4d519a517.nupkg
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.11.2.50704' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
Using C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\Plugins\CredentialProvider.Microsoft\CredentialProvider.Microsoft.exe as a credential provider plugin.
    [CredentialProvider.150559]Running in plug-in mode
    [CredentialProvider.150559]Command-line v0.1.23+3902a1eadc037829d4a161d287d8579f1fb2168e: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\Plugins\CredentialProvider.Microsoft\CredentialProvider.Microsoft.exe" -Plugin
    [CredentialProvider.150559]Handling 'Request' 'Initialize'. Time elapsed in ms: 3 - Payload: {"ClientVersion":"5.11.0","Culture":"en","RequestTimeout":"00:00:05"}
    [CredentialProvider.150559]Sending response: 'Request' 'Initialize'. Time elapsed in ms: 4
    [CredentialProvider.150559]Time elapsed in milliseconds after sending response 'Request' 'Initialize': 4
    [CredentialProvider.150559]Handling 'Request' 'GetOperationClaims'. Time elapsed in ms: 0 - Payload: {}
    [CredentialProvider.150559]Sending response: 'Request' 'GetOperationClaims'. Time elapsed in ms: 5
    [CredentialProvider.150559]Time elapsed in milliseconds after sending response 'Request' 'GetOperationClaims': 14
    [CredentialProvider.150559]Handling 'Request' 'SetLogLevel'. Time elapsed in ms: 0 - Payload: {"LogLevel":"Debug"}
    [CredentialProvider]Sending response: 'Request' 'SetLogLevel'. Time elapsed in ms: 1
    [CredentialProvider]Time elapsed in milliseconds after sending response 'Request' 'SetLogLevel': 3
    [CredentialProvider]Handling 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials'. Time elapsed in ms: 2 - Payload: {"Uri":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json","IsRetry":false,"IsNonInteractive":false,"CanShowDialog":true}
    [CredentialProvider]Creating a progress reporter with interval: 00:00:02
    [CredentialProvider]Handling auth request, Uri: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json, IsRetry: False, IsNonInteractive: False, CanShowDialog: True
    [CredentialProvider]URI: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
    [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpointCredentialProvider - This credential provider must be run under the Team Build tasks for NuGet with external endpoint credentials. Appropriate environment variable needs to be set.
    [CredentialProvider]Skipping NuGetCredentialProvider.CredentialProviders.VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpoint.VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpointCredentialProvider, cannot provide credentials for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
    [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - This credential provider must be run under the Team Build tasks for NuGet. Appropriate environment variables must be set.
    [CredentialProvider]Skipping NuGetCredentialProvider.CredentialProviders.VstsBuildTask.VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider, cannot provide credentials for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
    [CredentialProvider]GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
    [CredentialProvider]VstsCredentialProvider - Detected a hosted Azure DevOps Service.
    [CredentialProvider]Using NuGetCredentialProvider.CredentialProviders.Vsts.VstsCredentialProvider to try to get credentials for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.
    [CredentialProvider]IsRetry: False
    [CredentialProvider]Found cached SessionToken for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
    [CredentialProvider]Sending response: 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials'. Time elapsed in ms: 287
    [CredentialProvider]Time elapsed in milliseconds after sending response 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials': 289
  NotFound https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/7b1cdcb8-1d57-4320-8e01-c0226dfce5fc/nuget/v3/flat2/vcpkg-cmake-config_x64-windows/2021.5.22-vcpkgf4c47ca8e826891cf4e637ebaecbd8499efa3f7762b8c83c7aee03e4d519a517/vcpkg-cmake-config_x64-windows.2021.5.22-vcpkgf4c47ca8e826891cf4e637ebaecbd8499efa3f7762b8c83c7aee03e4d519a517.nupkg 672ms
  NotFound https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/7b1cdcb8-1d57-4320-8e01-c0226dfce5fc/nuget/v3/flat2/openssl_x86-windows/1.1.1-vcpkg6276bfbf618dc64e1eec5bff0593d9de2a6bef5a592c854b5f3d4940fe0ab899/openssl_x86-windows.1.1.1-vcpkg6276bfbf618dc64e1eec5bff0593d9de2a6bef5a592c854b5f3d4940fe0ab899.nupkg 653ms
WARNING: Unable to find version '1.1.1-vcpkg6276bfbf618dc64e1eec5bff0593d9de2a6bef5a592c854b5f3d4940fe0ab899' of package 'openssl_x86-windows'.
  https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json: Package 'openssl_x86-windows.1.1.1-vcpkg6276bfbf618dc64e1eec5bff0593d9de2a6bef5a592c854b5f3d4940fe0ab899' is not found on source 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json'.

WARNING: Unable to find version '2021.5.22-vcpkgf4c47ca8e826891cf4e637ebaecbd8499efa3f7762b8c83c7aee03e4d519a517' of package 'vcpkg-cmake-config_x64-windows'.
  https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json: Package 'vcpkg-cmake-config_x64-windows.2021.5.22-vcpkgf4c47ca8e826891cf4e637ebaecbd8499efa3f7762b8c83c7aee03e4d519a517' is not found on source 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json'.

  NotFound https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/7b1cdcb8-1d57-4320-8e01-c0226dfce5fc/nuget/v3/flat2/vcpkg-cmake_x64-windows/2021.2.28-vcpkgac851a136bb968268c3a69c870e0c3292e6c5d6a1f1ed3c70fec8c4868349def/vcpkg-cmake_x64-windows.2021.2.28-vcpkgac851a136bb968268c3a69c870e0c3292e6c5d6a1f1ed3c70fec8c4868349def.nupkg 1023ms
WARNING: Unable to find version '2021.2.28-vcpkgac851a136bb968268c3a69c870e0c3292e6c5d6a1f1ed3c70fec8c4868349def' of package 'vcpkg-cmake_x64-windows'.
  https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json: Package 'vcpkg-cmake_x64-windows.2021.2.28-vcpkgac851a136bb968268c3a69c870e0c3292e6c5d6a1f1ed3c70fec8c4868349def' is not found on source 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/EscherGroup/af2463ce-ebf3-45ed-9d30-62eabffef61f/_packaging/VCPkgFeed/nuget/v3/index.json'.

Restored 0 packages from NuGet in 3.305 s. Use --debug for more information.
Starting package 1/3: vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows
Building package vcpkg-cmake-config[core]:x64-windows...
-- Installing port from location: D:\ripostecore\vcpkg\buildtrees\versioning_\versions\vcpkg-cmake-config\2d4f997a32b8e8bfe98d12beb2bfe6be713c7086
-- Installing: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/vcpkg-cmake-config_x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake-config/vcpkg_cmake_config_fixup.cmake
-- Installing: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/vcpkg-cmake-config_x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake-config/vcpkg-port-config.cmake
-- Installing: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/vcpkg-cmake-config_x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake-config/copyright
-- Performing post-build validation
-- Performing post-build validation done
Installing package vcpkg-cmake-config[core]:x64-windows...
Elapsed time for package vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows: 96.17 ms
Starting package 2/3: vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows
Building package vcpkg-cmake[core]:x64-windows...
-- Installing port from location: D:\ripostecore\vcpkg\buildtrees\versioning_\versions\vcpkg-cmake\0e8bb94599a00fd9c61fd0ae524c22a067c21420
-- Installing: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/vcpkg-cmake_x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_configure.cmake
-- Installing: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/vcpkg-cmake_x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_build.cmake
-- Installing: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/vcpkg-cmake_x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_install.cmake
-- Installing: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/vcpkg-cmake_x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg-port-config.cmake
-- Installing: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/vcpkg-cmake_x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/copyright
-- Performing post-build validation
-- Performing post-build validation done
Installing package vcpkg-cmake[core]:x64-windows...
Elapsed time for package vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows: 124.7 ms
Starting package 3/3: openssl:x86-windows
Building package openssl[core]:x86-windows...
-- Installing port from location: D:\ripostecore\vcpkg\buildtrees\versioning_\versions\openssl\7e4d802e3bde4154c227c0dd1da75c719be9f07a
-- Downloading https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1n.tar.gz;https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.1/openssl-1.1.1n.tar.gz -> openssl-1.1.1n.tar.gz...
-- Extracting source D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/downloads/openssl-1.1.1n.tar.gz
-- Using source at D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/buildtrees/openssl/src/openssl-1-8a70f997ec.clean
-- Copying openssl release source files...
-- Copying openssl release source files... done
-- Configure x86-windows-rel
-- Configure x86-windows-rel done
-- Build x86-windows-rel
-- Build x86-windows-rel done
-- Copying openssl debug source files...
-- Copying openssl debug source files... done
-- Configure x86-windows-dbg
-- Configure x86-windows-dbg done
-- Build x86-windows-dbg
-- Build x86-windows-dbg done
-- Installing: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/openssl_x86-windows/share/openssl/copyright
-- Fixing pkgconfig file: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/openssl_x86-windows/lib/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
-- Fixing pkgconfig file: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/openssl_x86-windows/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
-- Fixing pkgconfig file: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/openssl_x86-windows/lib/pkgconfig/openssl.pc
-- Downloading https://repo.msys2.org/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-pkg-config-0.29.2-3-any.pkg.tar.zst;https://www2.futureware.at/~nickoe/msys2-mirror/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-pkg-config-0.29.2-3-any.pkg.tar.zst;https://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/msys2/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-pkg-config-0.29.2-3-any.pkg.tar.zst;https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-pkg-config-0.29.2-3-any.pkg.tar.zst;https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-pkg-config-0.29.2-3-any.pkg.tar.zst;https://mirror.bit.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-pkg-config-0.29.2-3-any.pkg.tar.zst;https://mirror.selfnet.de/msys2/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-pkg-config-0.29.2-3-any.pkg.tar.zst;https://mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-pkg-config-0.29.2-3-any.pkg.tar.zst -> msys-mingw-w64-i686-pkg-config-0.29.2-3-any.pkg.tar.zst...
-- Downloading https://repo.msys2.org/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-libwinpthread-git-9.0.0.6373.5be8fcd83-1-any.pkg.tar.zst;https://www2.futureware.at/~nickoe/msys2-mirror/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-libwinpthread-git-9.0.0.6373.5be8fcd83-1-any.pkg.tar.zst;https://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/msys2/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-libwinpthread-git-9.0.0.6373.5be8fcd83-1-any.pkg.tar.zst;https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-libwinpthread-git-9.0.0.6373.5be8fcd83-1-any.pkg.tar.zst;https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-libwinpthread-git-9.0.0.6373.5be8fcd83-1-any.pkg.tar.zst;https://mirror.bit.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-libwinpthread-git-9.0.0.6373.5be8fcd83-1-any.pkg.tar.zst;https://mirror.selfnet.de/msys2/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-libwinpthread-git-9.0.0.6373.5be8fcd83-1-any.pkg.tar.zst;https://mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/msys2/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-libwinpthread-git-9.0.0.6373.5be8fcd83-1-any.pkg.tar.zst -> msys-mingw-w64-i686-libwinpthread-git-9.0.0.6373.5be8fcd83-1-any.pkg.tar.zst...
-- Using msys root at D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/downloads/tools/msys2/9a1ec3f33446b195
-- Fixing pkgconfig file: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/openssl_x86-windows/debug/lib/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
-- Fixing pkgconfig file: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/openssl_x86-windows/debug/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
-- Fixing pkgconfig file: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/openssl_x86-windows/debug/lib/pkgconfig/openssl.pc
-- Installing: D:/ripostecore/vcpkg/packages/openssl_x86-windows/share/openssl/usage
-- Performing post-build validation
-- Performing post-build validation done
Installing package openssl[core]:x86-windows...
Elapsed time for package openssl:x86-windows: 2.187 min

Total elapsed time: 2.301 min

The package openssl is compatible with built-in CMake targets:

    find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto)
```

These are the resulting folders:
[Folders created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5cTO.png)

It works if I do `vcpkg.exe install openssl:x86-android` - I can see the x86-android in installed folder - but I'd like to do it via manifest mode.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you start with a new `vcpkg` folder after enabling manifest mode? I ask because I have seen comments about it won't work if you had an existing `vcpkg` folder with installed ports.

Comment: Ansewered by autoantwort via GitHub [Link to the GitHub discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/discussions/24247)

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

```
--triplet=x86-android
```

on the command line of the vcpkg manifest call (the default ist `x86-windows`).
Alternatively set the environment variable `VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET` to `x86-android`